# ClrMd - ClrInfo TryGetDacLocation and other method missing?

Tags: c#, debugging, trace, clrmd

I am trying out the ClrMd Library : 
https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd

And I have this issue, according to the first tutorial I have a method called **TryGetDacLocation** in ClrInfo type, but as I can find it in it... I can see that Dac location are generated automatically inside the Clrinfo but as I am trying to call  **runtimeInfo.CreateRuntime();** I am getting:
"Mismatched architecture between this process and the dac"

The dump and the running process are of the same - 32bit architecture.
I don't see that function and other, for instance - **TryDownloadDac** in the class :

https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/blob/4fa26f39c8c057abf0e2a67d735369ce4766fa07/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/ClrRuntime.cs

Any Ideas?

Comment: How did you take the dump file?

Comment: You are right,  I was taking the dump file from TaskManager but I wasn't aware that if I am taking 32 bit process from 64 TaskManger it will give me the 64 bit dump. So that's the issue here. And the TryGetDacLocation function are removed from the new version.. Thanks :)

Comment: Post that as an answer :)

Comment: I discovered another pretty interesting bug while testing this.  Building your program as AnyCPU cannot work, the debug engine returns the wrong path for clr.dll.  Its convinced that it came from the Framework directory instead of Framework64.  Hmm, this needs a lot more work to be smooth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was taking the dump file from TaskManager but I wasn't aware that if I am taking 32 bit process from 64 TaskManger it will give me the 64 bit dump. So that's the issue here.

And the TryGetDacLocation function are removed from the new version..

Thanks :)