# Replacement of TryGetDacLocation()

Tags: clrmd

On, [GitHub for ClrMd](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md), I read

```
// If we just happen to have the correct dac file installed on the machine,
// the "TryGetDacLocation" function will return its location on disk:
string dacLocation = version.TryGetDacLocation();
```

I have added ClrMd via NuGet. In the properties it says `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime` version 0.8.31.1 and that method is not available on the `ClrVersion` object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dump = DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(args[0]);
        dump.SymbolLocator.SymbolPath = @"srv*d:\debug\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols";
        // TODO: Hack. We assume that there's at least one runtime.
        ClrInfo clrVersion = dump.ClrVersions[0];
    }
}
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392598/clrmd-clrinfo-trygetdaclocation-and-other-method-missing) which states that the method was removed - but what do I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

The LocalMatchingDac property of the ClrInfo instance will give you the DAC location.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dump = DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(args[0]);
        dump.SymbolLocator.SymbolPath = @"srv*d:\debug\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols";
        // TODO: Hack. We assume that there's at least one runtime.
        ClrInfo clrVersion = dump.ClrVersions[0];
        // Get the DAC location
        string dacLocation = clrVersion.LocalMatchingDac;
    }
}
```

HTH

Doug

Comment: Please consider to provide a small code example demonstrating your solution